# Inline assembly in C not working properly

Tags: c, assembly

I'm trying to learn how to use inline assembly in C code.
I have created a small program that should add two integers:

```
int main(){
        int a=1;
        int b=2;
        asm(    "movl %0, %%r8d;"
                "movl %1, %%r9d;"
                "addl %%r8d, %%r9d;"
                "movl %%r9d, %1;"
                : "=r"  (a)
                : "r"   (b)
                :"%r8","%r9" );
        printf("a=%d\n",a);
        return 0;
}
```

The aim was to load `a` and `b` into the registers `%r8` and `%r9`, add them, and then put the output back in `a`.
However this program prints `a=2` instead `a=3`. I'm not sure if the problem is in the inline technique or in the assembly itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

First: The `"=r"` constraint you use for the output operand `a` indicates to the compiler that the operand is write-only — it is allowed to assume that the initial value is not needed. This is definitely not the case for your code! Change the qualifier to `"+r"` to let the compiler know that the initial value **is** important.

Second: You are moving the result to the wrong register! The target `%1` of the last `movl` is the register corresponding to `b`, not `a`. You want `%0`.

Fixed:

```
asm(
    "movl %0, %%r8d;"
    "movl %1, %%r9d;"
    "addl %%r8d, %%r9d;"
    "movl %%r9d, %0;"
    : "+r" (a)
    : "r"  (b)
    : "%r8", "%r9"
);
```

Comment: Thanks!
The second error is something I just changed when I saw it was not working. So I thought maybe I was using the wrong register.
Now it works!